# Installing environment for https://github.com/igorshubovych/markdownlint-cli fails with AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'tell' #328

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, nodeenv

I am using

```
- repo: https://github.com/igorshubovych/markdownlint-cli
    rev: v0.32.2
    hooks:
      - id: markdownlint
```

Sometimes, pre-commit fails with the following error.

```
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/igorshubovych/markdownlint-cli.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/usr/local/bin/python', '-mnodeenv', '--prebuilt', '--clean-src', '/root/.cache/pre-commit/repoki3l4r17/node_env-default')
return code: 1
stdout: (none)
stderr:
     * Install prebuilt node (19.8.1) .Incomplete read while readingfrom https://nodejs.org/download/release/v19.8.1/node-v19.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
    .
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 1519, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 1104, in main
        create_environment(env_dir, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 980, in create_environment
        install_node(env_dir, src_dir, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 739, in install_node
        install_node_wrapped(env_dir, src_dir, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 762, in install_node_wrapped
        download_node_src(node_url, src_dir, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 602, in download_node_src
        with ctx as archive:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 573, in tarfile_open
        tf = tarfile.open(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py", line 1630, in open
        saved_pos = fileobj.tell()
    AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'tell'
```

It looks like nodeenv-1.7.0 is used.

It happens randomly every third time or so. Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: recently there was an issue with nodejs.org where the results returned a 404 -- this resulted in this same error -- it should be resolved now?

Comment: Ok interesting! Have not had the issue for a day so hopefully, it's resolved :)